# Appropriate Mathematical Symbol for Percentage Representation: $=$ or $\implies$?

Tags: notation, percentages

I am unsure if this is the appropriate forum for my question, but I have been struggling to articulate it accurately while searching for a solution online. I am uncertain if I am overthinking the problem or approaching it incorrectly. I will do my best to explain the issue comprehensively.

To provide some context, I have been studying the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) $lev(a,b)$ and I came up with this formulated following equation:

$$p=\left(1-\frac{lev(a,b)}{m}\right)\times100$$

Above equation is used to represent the distance as a percentage in string matching, where $m$ is the length of the longest of the two words. The result is expressed as a percentage.

As part of my "String metric" presentation, I have substituted the equation with example strings. For instance, I have written $p = 80$%.

I am intrigued by the question of whether it is considered appropriate to use the equal sign when representing the decimal form of a percentage, even after multiplying by 100? Specifically, I am wondering if it is valid to express $p=80=0.8$ or simply $p=0.8$. This seems counterintuitive to me since $80$ is not equal to $0.8$ obvious, but it appears to be acceptable when dealing with percentages according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage). Wikipedia also employs the equal sign in similar contexts, such as for $0.20 = \frac{20}{100} = 20$%.

Hence, even if I multiply by 100, would $0.8$ or even $\frac{80}{100}$ still be correct?

Alternatively, I have thought of using the implication symbol $\implies$ to represent this scenario. I am uncertain whether it would be appropriate to use it in this context. For instance, would it be acceptable to write $p=80\implies0.8$ instead of $p=80=0.8$.

I appreciate any guidance or clarification you can provide. I apologize if this is not the appropriate forum for my question or if I am approaching it incorrectly. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: As far as I understand it, $80$% is $80/100$ by definition. If you've given the probability of an event the name $p$, I see no problem with the expression $p = 80$%; this tells us that the event has an $80$% chance of occurring.

Comment: Percent notation means $\,80\% = 80 \cdot 1\% = 80 \cdot \frac{1}{100} = 0.8\,$, because $\,1\% = \frac{1}{100}=0.01\,$ by definition. Your $p$ can be written as $p=0.8=80\%$ but you need to remove "$\times100$" from the formula.

Comment: You can also change $\times 100$ to $\times 100\%$, which is equivalent to $\times 1$.

Comment: Thank you. I have a further question regarding the correctness of the formula. I'm interested in knowing whether it is generally more widely accepted to use a variable name like $p$ or $p\%$ to imply that the expression represents a probability. In other words, when given the probability of an event, does the choice of using $p$ as the variable justify omitting the percent sign in the formula? Additionally, I would like to clarify the interpretation of the expression $p = 80$ then? Would it be understood as $80\%$ or $8000\%$. I would greatly appreciate your insights on this matter.

Comment: I encountered an interesting example in this [paper](https://www.ijrte.org/wp-content/uploads/papers/v7i6s5/F10070476S519.pdf). Similarly, the formula presented in the paper does not include the percentage sign after "x100".

On the fourth page (41) of the document, the representation is as follows:

$$Plagiarized Value = \left(1-\frac{2}{max(14)}\right)\times100=0,86$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When representing percentages, it is common to use the equal sign (=) to indicate equivalence between the percentage value and its decimal form. $80\%$ **can** be represented as $0.8$. This is because percentages are simply a way of expressing a proportion or ratio out of 100. So, saying "$p = 80\%$" is equivalent to saying "$p = 0.8$". Both statements convey the same information.

The implication symbol ($\implies$) is used to indicates a logical implication or deduction. It denotes that one statement logically implies another.

In the case of representing percentages, the implication symbol is not commonly used because there is no logical implication between the percentage value and its decimal form. It might even cause confusion. Instead, the equal sign ($=$) is used to show the equivalence.

To conclude, it is generally acceptable to use the equal sign ($=$) to represent the equivalence between a percentage value and its decimal form. So, you can write "$p = 80\% = 0.8$". Using the implication symbol ($\implies$) would **not** be appropriate in this context.

Comment: So, if I express it as follows:

$$p=\left(1-\frac{lev(a,b)}{m}\right)\times100=0.8$$

Would that be considered correct, similar to saying?

$$p=\left(1-\frac{lev(a,b)}{m}\right)\times100=80$$

I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: If you meant 80% at the end of the 2nd equation, they would be equivalent

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I mistakenly omitted the "%" sign at the end of 80. Therefore, it should be written as 80%.

Comment: Then they would be equivalent, though writing 0.8 is more common

Comment: I appreciate your prompt response. I apologize for deleting my previous comment, as I wanted to rephrase my question to ensure better clarity. Regarding the accuracy of the formula, I would like to know if it is more commonly accepted to use a variable name like $p$ to inherently imply that the expression represents a probability, thereby rendering the inclusion of a percent sign after 100 unnecessary. In other words, does the choice of variable $p$ suggest the probability, allowing for the omission of the percent sign in your formula? Your insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot answer that. Maybe you should post that as a separate question?